# How to Invoke contract function on react app?

Tags: anchor, rust, frontendintegration

Is there any reference there for

> How to Invoke contract function on react app

I deploy the staking contract on Solana Devnet. The staking program is created using the anchor framework, and now I am trying to Integrate that staking program with Ui(which I am creating using react js).so Is there any reference GitHub repo or docs for staking available?

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to follow this [example](https://dev.to/edge-and-node/the-complete-guide-to-full-stack-solana-development-with-react-anchor-rust-and-phantom-3291)

- Anchor backend
- React Frontend
- Wallet using [Solana Wallet Adapter](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter)

The main advantage of using `Anchor` with `React` is reusing the test code in your `/tests` folder